# Showing $S_{n}$ is not solvable for $n\geq 5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm going through a physicist viewpoint of Galois theory and a found a lecture by Takeuchi [here](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/project/MISC/slide/seminar-s/2011/120112Takeuchi.pdf). In the slide 47 he showed that $S_{n}$ is not solvable for $n\geq 5$. This is the proof

Let $G$ be a group of permutations of five objects or more that
include all cyclic permutations of three elements.

$(124)(142)=e$

$(135)(153)=e$

$(123)=(124)(135)(142)(153)$

Let $H$ be an invariant normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/H$ is cyclic. And consider the homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow G/H$

$f[(124)]=x$

$f[(135)]=y$

$f[(123)]=f[(124)(135)(142)(153)]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=e$

Therefore $(123)\in H$. This is true for any cyclic permutation of three
elements. Therefore, $G$ is not solvable.

I don't understand particularly why the fact that $(123)$ is mapped to the identity implies $(123)\in H$. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That map from $G$ onto $G/H$ is the map $g\mapsto gH$ and the identity element of $G/H$ is $H(=eH)$. So, $g(\in G)$ is maped into $eH$ if and only if $gH=eH$, which means that $g\in H$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: By the way, when he says "This is true for any cyclic permutation of three elements " I'm assuming it is because for $n\geq 5$ every $3-$cycle is conjugate to $(123)$ in $A_{n}$, Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, that's it.